# How to set Loader in Sweet Alert 2?

Tags: jquery, sweetalert2

I'm using **Sweetalert** version 2 in my project
I read the document of **Sweetalert** but I couldn't find how can I set loader while press confirm button 
if anyone experienced that please answer this question 
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue
showLoaderOnConfirm is no longer necessary. Your button will automatically show a loding animation 
just you need to set:
 **closeModal: false**
 in your confirm button